# Posso usar charset ANSI em arquivos HTML?

Tags: html, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8, unicode, iso-8859-1

Para eu poder públicar textos diariamente usando um editor qualquer como o notepad++ por exemplo, gostaria de digitar as palavras com acento e assim salva-las no arquivo HTML. Andei lendo que o **UTF-8** é necessário colocar um código para os acentos. 
Por exemplo o ***é*** corresponde a `&eacute;`.

Gostaria de saber se posso usar charset **ANSI** em arquivos HTML para não precisar estar digitando os códigos **UTF-8** para cada caractere especial ou acento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está confuso, UTF-8 não tem nada a ver com as "HTML entities" como `&eacute;`. O UTF-8 é uma maneira de se representar os caracteres em *bytes*, assim como o ANSI (Windows-1252, semelhante ao ISO-8859-1, ou Latin 1). A diferença é que os caracteres ANSI usam sempre 1 *byte* cada, enquanto em UTF-8 usa-se de 1 a 4 *bytes*. Portanto, com UTF-8 é possível representar uma quantidade muito maior de caracteres especiais.

Hoje em dia, é altamente recomendado usar UTF-8 em vez de ANSI ou outra codificação mais limitada. Se os arquivos estiverem salvos como UTF-8 e o HTML estiver sendo entregue pelo servidor com os cabeçalhos HTTP corretos, tudo irá funcionar sem problemas.

Comment: Você está querendo dizer que posso sair digitando normalmente com acentos desde que  meu charset esteja como UTF-8 e o arquivo salvar como UTF-8. Ok tudo bem. E quando devo usar `&eacute;` ?? para que existe esse tipo de codificação?

Comment: Isso, pode digitar normalmente :) Você raramente precisa usar `&aacute;` e similares, a menos que esteja querendo evitar que  código HTML gerado por usuários seja interpretado.